# Create database schema diagram from .sql file for mysql

Tags: mysql

Is there any database schema generation tool that creates schema diagram 
by importing the mysql .sql database schema file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-gui.html) is what you're looking for.

I haven't done it myself, but it does support [importing of SQL files](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-importing-sql-script.html).

Comment: I use MySQL Workbench for all my DB development.  It's a GREAT tool.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can point your existing DB to Workbench and create a schema graphically and do what ever changes you prefer.

Then you can export a set of new changes to a different SQL so, you can easily upgrade your production databases.